# PhoneGap 'find' undefined when using contact api

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am using jquery mobile and phonegap to display all contacts from android.  This is my js

```
$('#contactBtn').click(function() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";
    options.multiple=true;
    filter = ["displayName"];
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, contactSuccess, contactErr, options);
});

function contactSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
}
function contactErr(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

Chrome has this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined."

What did I done wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is phonegap.js getting loaded? Do you have a line like

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

and does the name of the phonegap-{version}.js match the one in the www directory?

Comment: yes it is. attachment order is jquery core, then mobile then phonegap.

Comment: and where is your js that includes the code that calls "find"?

Comment: i have a good connection with phonegap.  I am using its storage api and camera.  but failed on contacts.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem as well using phonegap version 2.7.0.  If you create the project properly you will notice you have cordova-2.7.0.js in the www file you need to set the source to that.